# How to redirect the client when socket gets disconnected in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I want to redirect the client to some page on socket disconnection, Is it possible and how ?

I want this to handle when there are abrupt disconnections like server got crashed or internet disconnectivity etc.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.io` fires a disconnect event on disconnection. Add this to client side:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        alert('Server disconnected! Check your net connection');
        window.location = "/unsupported.html"; //page you want to redirect
});
```